# How to avoid deepcopy of Python 2.7 class instances?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

I'm running an evolutionary algorithm to optimise functions within a separate simulation environment (also written in Python). The simulation environment itself is a python class instance, and is computationally expensive (~4 seconds per run) and takes up about 1Gb of memory. As I'm generating about a hundred thousand different functions to test in this simulation environment, I need a way to take as much of the simulation off-line as possible.

What I can do is pre-compute the majority of the simulation (i.e. initialise an instance of the class and then run some sub-set of class functions) and then fire in the algorithm for only a small component (e.g. the remaining few functions within the class). This in general reduces the evaluation time to ~1 sec, which improves the run-time significantly.

However, every time a new function is passed into the simulation class instance, the class instance is changed by the function (and thus affects the outcome of the next function evaluation). I can prevent this from happening by doing a deepcopy of the entire class instance before every evaluation, but that ends up being slower than running the entire simulation each time.

Is there a way to avoid deepcopying the entire class at each stage but to get the same result? Essentially each function evaluation needs to be performed on exactly the same class instance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out this issue is an issue with Python's [Multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) class (which I hadn't mentioned as I thought it wasn't part of the problem). Each worker in the pool by default lives for the entire length of time the pool is open. All processes executed by a single worker remain in the memory at any one time, and since a single class instance is passed to those workers, that class instance is updated every time a solution is executed. The simple way to solve this is by using Multiprocessing.Pool's "maxtasksperchild" argument to limit the number of tasks a single worker can handle before it is killed and a new one spawned in its place. Setting this value to 1 has solved all of my issues.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve the issue of your evolving classes directly, but I have had very good experience with the performance of [cPickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) for saving class instances. I use it to save the state of custom data structures, which are quite large, and loading and saving are very fast operations.